# Non-null hex char input interpreted as null in C

Tags: c, parsing, char, hex, scanf

We have a piece of code to illustrate the danger of buffer overflows to bypass a password hash. My input to crack the password consists of a string of hex chars being input through the commandline as below:

```
echo -ne "\xab\x94\x44..." | ./checkPassword
```

This is parsed in checkPassword by:

```
scanf("%29s", password);
```

I then print the password with both:

```
printf("\n%s", password):
```

and

```
for (i=0; i<29; i++) {
    printf("%c ", password[i]);
}
```

The input string is captured by checkPassword using scanf. I am *very* certain the method I use to generate the cracking string "\x..." is correct. However, I noticed that sometimes I still don't bypass the password. Upon printing out the input strings as read by checkPassword I noticed that chars such as \xc were being interpreted as \x00 and that if they hadn't been, I would have bypassed the password. I haven't found any of fixing or explaining this. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks for any suggestions

EDIT: providing more code.

EDIT2: \xc also means that the program ignores any chars that come after it. This isn't the only char that causes the problem, but they all seem to be "< \xc" I think. Unfortunately, just forbidding values less than that isn't really feasible due to the fact that I don't have direct control over the chars themselves.

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. We can't speculate on code we can't see.

Comment: Added some more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scanf stops at whitespace symbols:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

> s String of characters    Any number of non-whitespace characters, stopping at the first whitespace character found. A terminating null character is automatically added at the end of the stored sequence.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isspace/

> For the "C" locale, white-space characters are any of:

```
' '     (0x20)  space (SPC)
'\t'    (0x09)  horizontal tab (TAB)
'\n'    (0x0a)  newline (LF)
'\v'    (0x0b)  vertical tab (VT)
'\f'    (0x0c)  feed (FF)
'\r'    (0x0d)  carriage return (CR)
```

Comment: Oh my goodness, I didn't know there was a page on what is and isn't white space! I think this should absolutely solve my problem, thank you. I'll mark as correct for now and will verify asap.

Comment: Please do not link to C++ documentation for C questions.